# Как запретить отправку ajax формы, если не все поля заполнены?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

у меня проблема, при валидации формы с помощью плагина validation.js, даже если не все поля заполнены, происходит отправка данных на сервер. Как запретить отправку, если не все поля заполнены?

```
$("#myForm").validate({
      rules: {
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
        name: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 5
        }
      }
    });
    $('#btn_submit').click(function(){
                // собираем данные с формы
                var user_name    = $('#user_name').val();
                var user_email   = $('#user_email').val();
                var user_phone = $('#user_phone').val();
                var user_town = $('#user_town').val();
                // отправляем данные
                $.ajax({
                    url: "action.php", // куда отправляем
                    type: "post", // метод передачи
                    dataType: "json", // тип передачи данных
                    data: { // что отправляем
                        "user_name":    user_name,
                        "user_email":   user_email,
                        "user_phone":   user_phone,
                        "user_town":    user_town 
                    },
                    // после получения ответа сервера
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#thank').css({'display': 'block'});
                        $('#my_modal').css({'display': 'none'});
                    }
                });
            });
```

вот html

```
<form id="myForm" role="form">
                        <div class="in">
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="user_name" placeholder="Ваше имя*"><br>
                            <input type="text" name="phone" id="user_phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон*"><br>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="user_email" placeholder="Ваш email*"><br>
                            <input type="text" name="town" id="user_town" placeholder="Ваш город*"><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modalPar">
                            <p>Нажимая на кнопку «Получить презентацию», Вы подтверждаете, что ознакомились с <a href="">Политикой конфиденциальности.</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <button class="button" id="btn_submit">
                            <p>Получить презентацию</p>
                            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
```

http://a0447933.xsph.ru/ ссылка на сайт, на всякий случай. Валидация подключена, только к первой форме, на ней все тестирую. Дело в том, что даже при не заполнении всех полей форма отправляется на почту и появляется всплывающее окно об успешной отправке, а такого быть не должно. Помогите, пожалуйста!!!

Comment: А что мешает использовать required в элементах формы?

Comment: @Denis I, спасибо, о самом очевидном не подумал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cамое простое так

```
 // собираем данные с формы
var user_name    = $('#user_name').val();
var user_email   = $('#user_email').val();
var user_phone = $('#user_phone').val();
var user_town = $('#user_town').val();
if( user_name && user_email && user_phone && user_town ){
     // т.к. ""==true //> false
     // отправляем данные
     $.ajax({ ....
} else {
     //сообщаем юзеру об ошибке
     alert ('друг, заполни плиз все поля');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, но теперь страница перезагружается при отправке, как от этого избавится?

Comment: Спасибо, уже не надо, в функции клика на кнопку вставил return false;